# Can I install an AFCI outlet in series to a GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 100amp fuse panel and I have already installed some GFCI outlets as the first device for each circuit. This is working fine. I had tried to find some AFCI/GFCI combo outlets with no luck(Halifax, Nova Scotia). I want to install a couple of AFCI outlets before the GFCI outlets and feed through those as well. I don't know if they would both work that way or if only one or the other would work. Hoping somebody has tried this already or knows the answer. Tried to post a pic, but can't get to site([http://imgur.com/upload](https://imgur.com/upload)). Thanks in advance. Site is working again.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7oWb.jpg

Comment: Why not get combo AFCI/GFCI breakers instead and use regular outlets? They are a bit pricey but not much more than a pair of good quality GFCI and AFCI outlets. Also the protective systems are not prone to interfering with each other.

Comment: I have fuse, not breakers.

Comment: I suspect the prime issue would be a coordination failure on hard ground faults (i.e. a race-to-trip scenario where you can't predict what trips ahead of time).  I'd need to test to see if OBC AFCIs trip on gross ground faults, though...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I guess I will take a chance on them as it will be cheaper than replacing a panel. I was going to do that but the Power Co  came out to to look at my service and said they would have to upgrade to 200 amp and install a new mast up through my eave. All I wanted to do was swap the panel for another 100 amp breaker panel which I could afford. Just the cost of them coming out for 2 trips will cover a couple receptacles. Thank you!

Comment: I would call the power company and ask to talk to someone else. Code still allows single family residences to have a 100A service in the U.S.